# display the names of GISTs with octokit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, octokit

I am using github api for GISTs and I find a gem octokit
I arrived well recovered my GISTs.

The problem I have is to get the name because it adds the key like this

```
files: {
  gistfile1.js: {
  filename: "gistfile1.js",
  type: "application/javascript",
  language: "JavaScript",
  size: 231,
  truncated: false,
 }
```

How I could browse the files without knowing the key because I have tried several solutions but none works.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean you need an array of the filenames returned from octokit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you mean, I believe it is because the Octokit gem does not return hashes but rather similar looking Sawyer::Resource objects. Try this:

```
gists = Octokit.gists 'username'
files = gists.map{|g| g[:files] }.map{|f| f.to_h.keys }
file_names = files.flatten.map(&:to_s)
```